# AutoCAD alternative with source/destination feature?

Tags: cad

I want to make an electrical drawing for some cabinets and I really like autoCAD but at my new workplace I am not allowed to use that because of the cost. So I am looking for a decent alternative.

So far I have not found a cheap/free alternative to autoCAD that has some of the specific features I want.

What I primarily want in my CAD program is being able to create references(the source and destination feature) between .dwg files, so that if I view them as a .pdf I can click on the links and be taken to the part that the reference links to:

[image]

[image]

I have tried LibreCAD, NanoCAD, DraftSight and I could not find the features I was looking for in those programs... I have a hard time finding these features just by looking on the surface on these programs so that is why I'm asking here if anyone can help me with some pointers...

Help and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

My mistake was partially not being specific enough, I should have looked for autoCAD *electrical* alternatives. libreCAD etc. are not for electrical schematics the same way autoCAD electrical is, they just work as alternatives for regular autoCAD.

It took a while to find but so far ProfiCAD has the tools I am looking for, although links do not work when converted to pdf:s unlike autoCAD electrical if I remember correctly... But it runs a whole lot smoother. It still costs money but not nearly as much and seems acceptable for the budget.